# Insert Linq query part inside existing query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, abstract-syntax-tree

Having the following variable which stores an `IQueryable`:

```
var mainQuery = session
    .Query<Employee>()
    .Select(e => new
    {
        e.Name,
        e.Address
    });
```

And a method which takes that IQueryable as parameter.

```
public DataTable GetData(IQueryable query)
{
    ...
}
```

How can I write code inside `GetData()` that adds `OrderBy()` before the `Select()`?

Final value of `query` should look like it was built using following Linq expression:

```
var query = session
    .Query<Employee>()
    .OrderBy(e => e.Age)
    .Select(e => new
    {
        e.Name,
        e.Address
    });
```

This is required because if I add the `OrderBy()` after `Select()` I will only be able to sort by the members of the anonymous type (name, address). If an employee would also have and age, I could not sort by it when placing `OrderBy()` after `Select()`.
Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE:**

`GetData` has no knowledge of the structure of the query except that it ends with a `Select`.
And it has to have that exact signature `public DataTable GetData(IQueryable query)` - no extra parameters.

What is required it to modify the existing query inside the method and add `OrderBy` before the `Select`.

When there will be a correct answer I will accept and vote for it.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just apply the `select()` after the call to `GetData()`?

```
var mainQuery = session.Query<Employee>();

this.GetData(mainQuery);

mainQuery.OrderBy(x => x.Age)
         .Select(x => new
                 {
                     x.Name,
                     x.Address
                 });
```

Linq expression trees are immutable ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546136.aspx)).  You have to create a copy of the tree in parts to modify it.

**Update:** Keep in mind your pattern is trying to separate data access from presentation (or at least that is how it reads).  Ordering is a matter of presentation.  You may have multiple clients wanting to use GetData to fetch data but each of those clients might want the data to be sorted differently.  Your original query projected after the call to GetData anyway so it makes sense to order with the projection.

Now if you REALLY want to order inside the method without changing its contract, you have to walk the expression tree of the linq query and rebuild it from scratch injecting the ordering in the right place.  Expression trees are **immutable** and cannot be modified in-place.

Comment: I could do that, but that was not the question. Consider modifying the query inside `GetData` a contract - adding `OrderBy` has to be done there. If it could have been done as you answered, there would not have been any question.

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense that `GetData` should be responsible for ordering the data.  IF in your scenario above having the `select` outside of the `GetData` is valid, then it also makes sense to order there too.  `GetData` should be responsible for just fetching the data.  Ordering is merely a presentation issue which belongs with your `select` which is also a presentation issue.  If you had multiple callers to `GetData` it may make sense they each of the callers expect the data to be sorted differently.  That is why ordering is a matter of presentation and should be handled one level up.

Comment: `GetData()` is just some name I picked as an example, it is the method used by `ObjectDataSource` so it needs to do paging/sorting inside it. If I use `OrderBy` after the projection I won't be able to sort by any field of `Employee`, `Age` for example, won't be available for sorting after `Select`. Rebuilding the expression tree was what I was looking for, I didn't knew `IQueryable` was immutable. +1 for added value, you said how, but at very high level :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider creating `ViewModel` or `DTO` for `Employee` and not to pass anonymous objects around. But anyway you can pass `selector` into `GetData` and apply it after sorting `Employee`

```
var mainQuery = session.Query<Employee>();

GetData(mainQuery, e => new { e.Name, e.Address });

//object is used because you create anonymous objects and pass them around
public DataTable GetData(IQueryable query, 
                         Expression<Func<Employee, object>> selector)
{
    return query.OrderBy(e => e.Age)
                .Select(selector)
                //...
}
```

Comment: it's seems to be that your method is not correct, you should get an Expression<Func<Employee, object>>

Comment: @lamStalker thanks for note. My EF version works with `Func` as well, but generated `sql` is optimized in case of `Expression`

Comment: No problem it's a pleasure to help

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: This does not answer the question since it modifies the signature of `GetData`.